# Copy selection only in visual mode VIM (no gui vim) to system clipboard

Tags: macos, vim

Is it possible? Every solution I've found online somehow doesn't meet one of the following criteria:

- vim, no macvim
- osx only
- visual mode only (for copying at least)
- must be able to copy only selection, and not entire line
- must copy to system clipboard

Answer (score 2):

There is special "*" register, witch reference system clipboard.
"*y
"*p
It should work on console vim on every OS (I use vim on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

The default Vim that comes with Mac OS X is not built with clipboard support. It is [possible](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_clipboard_sharing) to use `pbpaste` and `pbcopy` as a workaround but not very practical.

A much better long-term solution is to…

1. download [MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases),
2. put MacVim.app in `/Applications/` or `~/Applications/`,
3. put `mvim` in one of the directories listed in `$ echo $PATH`,
4. do `$ mvim -v filename` to edit `filename` with MacVim's CLI executable,
5. use `"+y` to yank to and `"+p` to put from the system clipboard.